# Saving mostly white space images - high file size, want lower

Tags: c#

I'm saving some A4 images and smaller images to file.

I want to know what is the best format. They come back from a scan that is grayscale only. However some of the images are quite large in size (compared to what we would expect).

We have tried saving them as JPEG with different qualites but still can't get them as small as we'd like, is JPEG not the most effecient format for this.

A4 Saved at quality 8 is saving as 196KB
smaller image saved at quality 8 is saving as 28KB

Because so much of this image is white space we expected much smaller file sizes.  File size is more important here than image quality.
Are we doing something wrong?

Here is sample A4 Image
[image]

Here is sample smaller Image 
[image]

Our code is written in c#

```
  // Get a bitmap.
    Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(@"c:\TestImageFromScanner.jpg");
    ImageCodecInfo jgpEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    // Create an Encoder object based on the GUID 
    // for the Quality parameter category.
    System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder =
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;

    // Create an EncoderParameters object. 
    // An EncoderParameters object has an array of EncoderParameter 
    // objects. In this case, there is only one 
    // EncoderParameter object in the array.
    EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);

    EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder,8L);
    myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
    bmp1.Save(@"c:\TestJpegQuality8.jpg", jgpEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
```

Comment: You can just test the encoders on your test set. We will not beable to test this for you.

Comment: But is there a best image format for images that are grayscale and mostly whitespace?

Comment: TIFF seems pretty popular with copiers. Although you might want to look at JBIG2.

Comment: Are you looking for diskspace vs quality? There is no best format. If there was, we would be using the same format, would we?

Comment: Have you tried PNG? When I reduce your test image to 1 bit black/white and save as PNG it's about 61 KiB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a function to convert the image to black or white only, using a threshold. This greatly reduced the image size with the quality not vastly reduced.

```
    var downsizeImage = ImageTools.ConvertToBitonal(scaledBmp, 500);
                    downsizeImage.Save(string.Format(@"C:\Temp\{0}Downsized.png", betSlipImage.BetSlipID), ImageFormat.Png);
                    var ms = new MemoryStream();
                    downsizeImage.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

   public static Bitmap ConvertToBitonal(Bitmap original, int threshold)
        {
            Bitmap source;

            // If original bitmap is not already in 32 BPP, ARGB format, then convert
            if (original.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
            {
                source = new Bitmap(original.Width, original.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                source.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(source))
                {
                    g.DrawImageUnscaled(original, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                source = original;
            }

            // Lock source bitmap in memory
            var sourceData = source.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, source.Width, source.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            // Copy image data to binary array
            var imageSize = sourceData.Stride * sourceData.Height;
            var sourceBuffer = new byte[imageSize];
            Marshal.Copy(sourceData.Scan0, sourceBuffer, 0, imageSize);

            // Unlock source bitmap
            source.UnlockBits(sourceData);

            // Create destination bitmap
            var destination = new Bitmap(source.Width, source.Height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
            destination.SetResolution(original.HorizontalResolution, original.VerticalResolution);

            // Lock destination bitmap in memory
            var destinationData = destination.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, destination.Width, destination.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

            // Create destination buffer
            imageSize = destinationData.Stride * destinationData.Height;
            var destinationBuffer = new byte[imageSize];

            var sourceIndex = 0;
            var destinationIndex = 0;
            var pixelTotal = 0;
            byte destinationValue = 0;
            var pixelValue = 128;
            var height = source.Height;
            var width = source.Width;

            // Iterate lines
            for (var y = 0; y < height; y++)
            {
                sourceIndex = y * sourceData.Stride;
                destinationIndex = y * destinationData.Stride;
                destinationValue = 0;
                pixelValue = 128;

                // Iterate pixels
                for (var x = 0; x < width; x++)
                {
                    // Compute pixel brightness (i.e. total of Red, Green, and Blue values) - Thanks murx
                    //                           B                             G                              R
                    pixelTotal = sourceBuffer[sourceIndex] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 1] + sourceBuffer[sourceIndex + 2];
                    if (pixelTotal > threshold)
                    {
                        destinationValue += (byte)pixelValue;
                    }
                    if (pixelValue == 1)
                    {
                        destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
                        destinationIndex++;
                        destinationValue = 0;
                        pixelValue = 128;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pixelValue >>= 1;
                    }
                    sourceIndex += 4;
                }

                if (pixelValue != 128)
                {
                    destinationBuffer[destinationIndex] = destinationValue;
                }
            }

            // Copy binary image data to destination bitmap
            Marshal.Copy(destinationBuffer, 0, destinationData.Scan0, imageSize);

            // Unlock destination bitmap
            destination.UnlockBits(destinationData);

            // Dispose of source if not originally supplied bitmap
            if (source != original)
            {
                source.Dispose();
            }

            // Return
            return destination;
        }
```

Answer (score 6):

> But is there a best image format for images that are grayscale and mostly whitespace?

Looking at your image it's monochrome, not grayscale. And if monochrome is acceptable, you can use [JBIG2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JBIG2) to compress your documents.

It has particular optimisations for text (among other things):

> Ideally, a JBIG2 encoder will segment the input page into regions of text, regions of halftone images, and regions of other data. Regions which are neither text nor halftones are typically compressed using a context-dependent arithmetic coding algorithm called the QM coder. Textual regions are compressed as follows: the foreground pixels in the regions are grouped into symbols. **A dictionary of symbols is then created and encoded, typically also using context-dependent arithmetic coding, and the regions are encoded by describing which symbols appear where.**

Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 1):

For images with large blocks of flat color, consider using PNG-8.

However, ta.speot.ls's suggestion in this case looks like it would meet your needs better.

Comment: I appreciate the deference to my answer but .NET JBIG2 libraries are a pain in the ass to find. PNG8 might win simply by being more accessible.

Comment: How do I go about encoding to PNG8 with c#?

Comment: Yeah I've been googling for JBIG2 for a bit there a lot of paid for libraries coming up.

Comment: Try `ImageFormat.Tiff` too

Answer (score 0):

Lossless compression groups pixels of the same color. If there are 100 white pixels it stores "hundred white pixels" instead of "white pixel, white pixel....." 100 times.

Your images have large areas of white color. If you want it to compress well it has to be the exact same white. So quantize your images. Just reduce the number of color.

I guess you just need it to be readable as proof of something, so you don't need greyscale.

The best results will be 1 bit depth (2 colors black and white), PNG and tiff give good results.

If you can afford spending more time on this, you could do some more processing like removing lone pixels (noise).

Avoid JPEG wich was made for photos.